# Is info@mydomain a bad choice for the sender and reciever of bulk email newsletters

Tags: spam-prevention, bulk-email

Is it bad to use `info@mydomain.com` as the sender and receiver for bulk email newsletters?
Would it be better to use, for example `newsletter@mydomain.com`. I realise there are many factors that effect the spam score but ceteris paribus would this have an effect? Would some spam filters give info@ a negative rating or should I not be to concerned about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Would it be better to use, for example newsletter@mydomain.com**

Yes, using `newsletter@mydomain.com` would be a better choice. The reasons are:

- As covered [here](http://www.emailaudience.com/from-address-dos-and-donts-for-your-email-newsletter/), using the prefix `newsletter` is more descriptive and contextual - it helps convey the content of the message to the recipient, whereas `info` is too generic to convey anything.
- Spammers often target generic `info@mydomain.com` email addresses, adding it to the `from` address as well as to the list of `to` addresses, so when spam email gets rejected, sometimes the `from` address will end up in the spam complaint or blocked by ISP's and network servers.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer, I will stop using info@ for newsletters.

Comment: No problem - something more descriptive might increase the number of opens as well.